# What type of connectors do I need for wifi aerial to router connection? Not Ethernet

Tags: wireless-networking, router, connection, cable

I have a ZTE Home Broadband router that has 2 very small sockets for an external aerial and I would like to know what they are called so that I can get the proper cable with the right size plugs. I have a Poynting 4G Xpol A0001 antenna with SMA plugs but the aerial outlets on the router are much smaller. Can I get an SMA reducer/connector?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "a ZTE Home Broadband router" isn't enough info to be able to look it up. What exact model do you have?

Comment: It’s a ZTE model: MC801A

Comment: Instead of answering in the comments, add the info to your question (this and the Huawei thing). All relevant info go in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The antenna connectors on the **ZTE MC801A** 5G router are [**TS-9** (or TS9)](https://halberdbastion.com/resources/hardware/rf-connectors/rf-connector-series/ts-9) RF connectors.

To connect it to a device/cable with an SMA connector, like the *Poynting XPOL-1*, you can use **TS9 Male to SMA** adapters. (Of course that doesn't mean that it will work, not all devices work with all antennas.)

Comment: I had  an Huawei router before this upgrade which had the usual SMA connections but this new router had much smaller outlets.

Comment: Thank you for all your quick responses to my query. If I am correct it seems I need a TS9 Male to SMA adapter. I shall investigate. Thanks again.